# How to create a YAML file to deploy to azure using Azure pipelines and Azure Repos

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml

I'm trying to deploy some stuff in azure but I need to deploy it via Pipelines. I've searched examples but all of them are using an existing yaml file and I want to know what is the  right way to do ii cause I want to do it since scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below steps to create a new pipeline.
For the complete documentation from Microsoft on creating a new pipeline from scratch see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-a-build-pipeline

[image]